# Hello, I am using ubuntu 14.04 system and installed logstash 2.2.0 on it. When starting the logstash filebeat getting the following error:

Tags: logstash

```
sudo service filebeat start
```

> Loading config file error: YAML config parsing failed on /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml: yaml: line 14: found character that cannot start any token. Exiting.

Comment: please, help me with this issue...

Comment: Have you looked at line 14 in filebeat.yml?

Comment: yes, it only contains path over there

Comment: Please post your `filebeat.yml` here. And if it s very long, post only the first 20 lines or so.

Comment: filebeat:
  # List of prospectors to fetch data.
  prospectors:
    # Each - is a prospector. Below are the prospector specific configurations
    -
      # Paths that should be crawled and fetched. Glob based paths.
      # To fetch all ".log" files from a specific level of subdirectories
      # /var/log/*/*.log can be used.
      # For each file found under this path, a harvester is started.
      # Make sure not file is defined twice as this can lead to unexpected behaviour.
    paths:
        - /var/log/auth.log
        - /var/log/syslog
        #- /var/log/*.log ..please check it out..

Comment: Try a yaml linter like this [one](http://www.yamllint.com/). It might help you spot the error.

Answer (score 2):

I formatted the **YAML** that you provided in your comment:

```
filebeat: 
   # List of prospectors to fetch data. 
   prospectors: 
      # Each - is a prospector. Below are the prospector specific configurations 
      - 
         # Paths that should be crawled and fetched. Glob based paths. 
         # To fetch all ".log" files from a specific level of subdirectories 
         # /var/log/*/*.log can be used. 
         # For each file found under this path, a harvester is started. 
         # Make sure not file is defined twice as this can lead to unexpected behaviour. 
         paths: 
            - /var/log/auth.log 
            - /var/log/syslog 
            #- /var/log/*.log
```

The corresponding configuration without comments is:

```
filebeat: 
  prospectors: 
    - 
      paths: 
        - /var/log/auth.log
        - /var/log/syslog
```

Try the cleaned up configuration. I guess you have a problem with forbidden characters. Please keep in mind that [tabs are not allowed in YAML.](http://www.yaml.org/faq.html) Do you happen to have a tab or another forbidden character in line 14?

For further information take a look at the [Filebeat Configuration Options](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-filebeat-options.html).